# Does express set() store a reference or a value

Tags: express

I am curious how express `set('name', ??)` function works.

I know it is attaching something to the the express application which can be utilized by `get('name')`. Is it storing a reference to whatever you are assigning or is it actually storing the value?

Ex:

```
      //mysql2.js
      var mysql2 = require('mysql2');

      //Set up connection
      module.exports = mysql2.createPool({
           host: 'localhost',
           user: 'user',
           database: 'database',
           password: 'password',
           waitForConnections: true,
           connectionLimit: 10,
           queueLimit: 0
      });
```

And within my express app (

```
 const app = express();

 app.set('mysql2', require('./mysql2'));
```

Will i be storing a reference to the `mysql2.createPool` function or will i actually be opening the pool and passing it throughout the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior doesn't depend by `set` function, but from what you pass in the property, in javascript scalar object are copied, complex object are passed by reference. So here inside the `mysql2` property is memorized a reference to an object, and the object is the result to the function call `mysql2.createPool`.